# CSS will-change breaks on Safari

Tags: html, css, sass

if I apply the `will-change: opacity;`property to my element with a fixed value of border radious, this will broke the css and not consider the overflow and the radius.

it just happens on Safari, the other browsers are ok.

```css
.card{
    border-radius: 80px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

.bg-image{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    will-change: opacity; // => COMMENT HERE and it's works
}

.card--content{
    z-index: 30;
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 20;
    will-change: height;
    transition: height 0.24s ease-in-out;
}

.card::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background: linear-gradient(180.49deg, rgba(136, 168, 187, 0.217) 40.63%, rgba(0, 122, 194, 0.7) 71.44%);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}
    
.card:hover::after{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="bg-image lazy entered loaded" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/600 x 600/cfcfcf/fff.png" aria-label="" data-ll-status="loaded" src="https://dummyimage.com/600 x 600/cfcfcf/fff.png">
  <div class="card--content">
  content
  </div>
</div>
```

someone had the same problem?
thanks

Comment: The CSS you have included is actually a CSS pre-processor language, please either add the tags for that language or include the output CSS it produces instead.

Comment: @DBS i change from SCSS to CSS. thanks

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution but I don't think is the best. But for now is the best solution that i found. Hope someone find a better one.

i'm using

```
-webkit-mask-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
        mask-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
```